# How do you understand this sentence as a native English speaker?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, conjunctions

I and my colleague, we tried a photo app. After taking a photo, there's a "Cancel" button. A popup says **"Are you sure you want to delete the photo before sharing it"** is shown when you choose "Cancel".

How do you understand it in this context, it asks to delete then share or to delete without sharing the photo?

Comment: "You have opted to delete the photo but you have not yet shared it. Are you sure you want to delete the photo without having shared it?" How could you share it after it has been [finally] deleted? Yes, there is an awkwardness in the phraseology you mention, but logic decrees what the meaning must be taken to be.